# Transforming columns to single cell row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to get a result in excel, although not really getting a successful output. My table is as follows:

```
Data Item    KPI
Customer ID  X12
Customer ID  X13
Customer ID  X14
Customer Name Y1
Customer Name Y2
```

Expected Outcome -

```
Data Item     Outcome
Customer ID   "X12";"X13";"X14"
Customer Name "Y1";"Y2"
```

I want the expected output to be in a SINGLE cell in excel. How do I proceed?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser ! Which version of Excel are you using (functions can be radically different between old and new, so it's very much relevant)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I think the key here is knowing how to use [UNIQUE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e), [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759), and [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c). There are ways to do this without access to those but it'll be more complicated. You may or may not have access to this as it which depends on  your version of Excel. If you can use them, this is one solution:

[image: Screenshot]

Formula in `F1` finds all the unique rows where `Data` is not blank. This is a [spilled array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531) so one formula returns values to multiple cells.

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:B,A:A<>""))
```

`H1` is just fixed text. The formula in `H2` (which is then copied down) combines all the values where the `Data` and `Item` match what's in `F:G`. It wraps each result in quotes (`""""` in a formula gives you just `"` as a text result) and combines them with a semicolon in between each.

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,""""&FILTER(C:C,(A:A=F2)*(B:B=G2),"")&"""")
```

It's important to use `(A:A=F2)*(B:B=G2)` instead of something like `AND(A:A=F2,B:B=G2)` because `AND` operates on the entire range at once and will return nothing if *any* of the results don't match.

---

If you want to write the formula in `H2` to automatically spill down (so you don't have to copy it) or return blank if the value in `F:F` is blank (so you can copy it down 1,000 rows and not worry about it again), there are ways to do that and I encourage you to look for them if you want that condition. This should get you started, though.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:B6),VSTACK(HSTACK(A1:B1,"Outcome"),HSTACK(x,BYROW(x,LAMBDA(y,TEXTJOIN(", ",,REPT(""""&C2:C6&"""",MMULT(N(A2:B6=y),{1;1})=2)))))))
```